# Most efficient way to convert two bytes into a 16bit value?

Tags: c++, byte, 16-bit, 8-bit

Say first byte = 2 (dec) and second byte = 1 (dec).

First byte therefore represents 257 (dec).
Second byte therefore represents 1 (dec).

So the (total) 16bit value is 258 (dec).

So if I do:

```
  (byte1*256)+byte2
```

Is that the 'proper' way to do it? Or is there a better way?

Thanks,
T.

Answer (score 4):

With most modern optimizers, there is no "proper" way of doing it: your code would be converted to whatever is fastest on your system, which may include

- **Loading bytes separately into lower and upper partial registers** - no transformation is going on, the bytes are loaded directly into their respective places.
- **Bit shifting the top byte and OR-ing in the lower byte** - something like `byte1<<8 | byte2`
- **Bit shifting the top byte and adding the lower byte** - same as above, except with a `+` instead of an `|`
- **Something completely different that works fast on your system** - Different architectures may have architecture-specific optimizations not described above.

In your source code you should concentrate on making your intentions clear to human readers: if it is multiplying by `256` that makes the most sense to your readers, then use multiplication; if it is bit shifting, then use bit shifting. The compiler will take care of making your code as efficient as possible.

Comment: I agree with your general sentiment, but I'd say that shifting and oring is the most often seen and best understood approach in my experience. + shouldn't be very surprising either, but the multiplication would make me double check the code.

Comment: @Voo Pretty much any compiler worth its salt these days converts `x * 256` to `x << 8`. Years ago, I saw a construct like `(byte1*256)+byte2` in a production code, and decided to optimize it a little with bit shifts and ORs. Much to my surprise, the compiled code did not have my shifts and ORs: it used `LDA byte2; LDB byte1` to load a "composite" register (option 1 from my answer). That was the day when I stopped taking optimizers lightly :):):)

Comment: I'm not talking about the compiler - I'd be horribly surprised if a modern compiler couldn't handle this situation well (depending on the multiplicand there's always stuff like `lea` around too). It's about readability: I've worked quite a bit with low-level stuff and I pretty much everywhere see shift and or approach. shift and add wouldn't surprise me either, but if I saw someone multiplying it'd cause me to at least double check their intentions

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
(byte1<<8) | byte2
```

But I'm thinking that there might be a catch here. If your `byte1` and `byte2` data types are only 1 byte (that is, 8 bits) in size, shifting probably won't help.

I think the way you've done it should be completely fine. However, for kicks, something like this would probably also work:

```
int16 total = byte1;
total = (total<<8) | byte2
```

Comment: (byte1<<8)&byte2 might be better

Comment: That really should be an `|` not `&` for hopefully obvious reasons! Fixed it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shift operator, which shifts bits:
(byte1 << 8) + byte2

Shifting left is the same as multiplying by powers of 2. In the above example,

(2 << 8) is the same as (0b 0000 0010 << 8) which is (0b 10 0000 0000).

We shift by 8 because there are 8 bits in a byte.